# how to pass variable with require() in PHP

Tags: php

I'm stuck trying to pass variables between 2 PHP files `a.php` and `b.php`  using `require()`. I learned that PHP variables have a single scope, which means that if `a.php` includes `b.php`, it can read its variables. However, I would like `b.php` to be able to read a variable from `a.php` with my current setup. For example, I can print out `$msg` if it is set in `b.php` but not `a.php`. Is there a simple way to do this?

`a.php`

```
<?php

$msg = "Welcome NEW USER ! We can't wait for you to check out our books!";
require("connect.php");
require("b.php");
$table = "SELECT * FROM `login`";
if ($query_run=mysqli_query($cnn,$table)){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO login (username,password) VALUES ('{$username}','{$pw}')";


if($cnn->query($sql)===TRUE){echo "Query ran successfully";}
else{echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".$cnn->error;}
}
else{die("table connection failed");}
$cnn.close();

?>
```

`b.php`

```
<?php
echo "<h1>".$msg."</h1>
<form action='' method='post'>
Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br>
Password: <input type='text' name='password'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
"


?>
```

Comment: if a.php includes/requires b.php, all vars in b are available in a. Use require_once on b.php for a.php, and require_once on a.php for b.php

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score -1):

Using $_SESSION will allow you to pass `data` between different files.

in `a.php`

```
$_SESSION['myName'] = "John";
```

in `b.php`

```
echo $_SESSION['myName']
```

Comment: You really should only use session to store variables *between sessions*, not between files.  You would be better of using globals, not sessions (as they have extra side-effects), but neither is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what your trouble is but your example **should** work.  This most definitely works:

`a.php`

```
<?php
$from_a = 'hey';
require "b.php";
print $from_b;
```

`b.php`

```
print $from_a;
$from_b = 'okay';
```

The above is perfectly valid PHP and will work as intended with no errors.  A script which is required by another script has full access to its variables and vice-versa.

Answer (score -1):

If you make require an infinite cycling occurs,try `require_once` in each file.
But the best solution is to create a third file be it c.php and include both b.php and a.php in it

Answer (score -1):

No need to use of session.

if PHP file is included in other PHP file then variables also accessible in included PHP file.

Example

```
<?php

$a = 1;
include 'filename.php';

?>
```

Then $a is accessible in filename.php.
use echo in included file and test..

Let me know if you feel any issue.

Answer (score -1):

> "which means that if a.php includes b.php, it can read its variables."

I think the concept is slightly different. When you call the language construct `require`, it will read and include the specified file **as if it were written in the calling file itself**.

So this:

```php
<?php

// File a.php
$somevar = 6;
require "b.php";

?>
```

```php
<?php

// File b.php
echo $somevar;

?>
```

Is effectively the same as

```php
<?php

// File a.php
$somevar = 6;

// File b.php
echo $somevar;

?>
```